# Apollo Federation - Hadling the error Entity -> `Entity` is an extension type, but `Entity` is not defined in any service

Tags: node.js, graphql, microservices, apollo-server, federation

I wonder if there is any chance to handle the Apollo Federation Error: **Apollo Federation - Hadling the error Entity -> `Entity` is an extension type, but `Entity` is not defined in any service**

The Scenario:
In my service "LocalizationService", I extend the Entity "Product" of the "Productservice" like this:

```
@Directive('@extends')
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
export default class Product {
  @Directive('@external')
  @Field(() => ID)
  id!: number
}
```

What if the service "Productservice" is down ?
I got the error:

```
Product -> `Product` is an extension type, but `Product` is not defined in any service
```

Is there a way to catch that error or set the entity as nullable in some way??

Comment: Do you solved this problem? Cause I get the exact same error with u stated. Can u let me know why is it happen?